# Enable authentication on OData endpoints (Asp.Net Core Web Api)

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm struggling with authentication in Web Api project that use OData.
I thought that configuring authentication like this:

```cs
services.AddODataAuthorization((options) =>
{
    options.ConfigureAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAd));
});
```

will be enough to enable authentication on all requests to OData endpoints. But no matter if token is passed, valid or invalid - api methods are always executed. HTTP 401 (unauthorized) is never returned.

In one of [the examples](https://github.com/OData/WebApiAuthorization/blob/master/samples/ODataAuthorizationSample/Models/AppModel.cs#L22) there is an explicit use of `HasReadRestrictions` method:

```
customers.HasReadRestrictions()
                .HasPermissions(p => p.HasSchemeName("Scheme").HasScopes(s => s.HasScope("Customers.Read")))
                .HasReadByKeyRestrictions(r => r.HasPermissions(p =>
                    p.HasSchemeName("Scheme").HasScopes(s => s.HasScope("Customers.ReadByKey"))));
```

Is it mandatory to configure all OData entities like that?

Comment: Are you using the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controllers or methods?

Comment: @JHBonarius yes. In that project I have normal api controllers on which authorization works well. Only OData controllers pass unauthenticated requests.

Comment: Is there some useful info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/basic-auth)?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding currently you have to specify `[Authorize]` attribute for all controllers including OData because they're not anyhow different from others. ODataController is derived from ControllerBase.

This is kind of weird because you have to specify the same things twice.

Scheme permissions will be exposed in `$metadata` endpoint but are not applied automatically.
There's [an authorization library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/introducing-the-odata-web-api-authorization-library/) that solves this thing adding a middleware. But it's in beta stage since 2020 and available only for OData < 8.x.

Now if you need to copy policies in EDM is questionable. For example I need it to be exposed in OpenAPI specification. Up to you to decide if you need them.